# conEmu: Is it possible to lock scrollbar and prevent it from auto scrolling down

Tags: scrolling, conemu

conEmu experts:

I have a script that prints a lot in a short time. So I want to disable the auto scrolling down when the script is running.

I don't want to use 'more' because it only allows turning next page by keyboard.

How to just make conEmu lock the scrollbar?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may only switch to alternative mode - Win+A or button on toolbar. That will be like a pause.

Locking scrollbar is useless, because when your output reaches the bottom of the scroll buffer, the contents will be scrolled upwards line by line, even if scrollbar is still at the end.

Comment: But it is still useful when the scroll buffer has capacity left. I use a couple of thousand lines for the console buffer height and all of my commands' output fit into that. It would be nice to read the beginning of the output while the process is still appending new lines to the console (like e.g. IntelliJ does).

Comment: I don't understand why there isn't a simple feature like auto-scrolling to keep the content aligned to your view... this is extremely annoying, and the pause "hack" is terrible, imo... I don't want to pause my process just so I can take a look at some error that happened, without it scrolling out of view.

Answer (score 3):

You can pause the output by pressing the Pause button on the keyboard, as explained here:
https://conemu.github.io/en/AlternativeBuffer.html#pause

> Also, you may press Pause key. It will pause most console applications (who just print text to ‘StdOut’). Press Pause key again to release.

Comment: @fixer1234 I have updated my answer. Thanks.